# Problemas para abrir puertos en IP Tables

Tags: centos, iptables, httpd

Buenos días actualmente tengo un servidor apache corriendo en CentOS6.9 si desactivo el iptables `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` puedo navegar desde un equipo en red local en apache, pero si lo inicio aun habiendo habilitado los puertos como se muestra en este ejemplo me bloquea:

```html
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Luego de abrir los puertos habilito el iptables me sigue bloqueando. Así que traté de verificar si los puertos están habilitados con el siguiente comando: `nmap localhost -p 80 | grep -i tcp` y obtuve el siguiente resultado: `80/tcp open  http`. Sin embargo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestra que el puerto esta abierto pero aun así no me deja acceder desde otro equipo en la red. Pero si lo apago: `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que me falta para que iptables me permita recibir respuestas de apache?

Anexo resultado del siguiente comando:

`$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puede ser que el puerto este abierto para recibir pero no para salir prueba `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` (o definir una regla específica para el puerto 80), `iptables --line -vnL` muestra las reglas de manera legible

Comment: Saludos amigo, el output tambien lo agregué y nada. Exactamente este comando: `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: luego de un save y restart deberían estar todas las reglas en `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` fijate si no se cambiaron de orden o si falta alguna

Comment: Luego de abrir usé el siguiente comando: `iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables` agregaré una nueva imagen con el resultado en el post del siguiente comando `cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Comment: yo moveria el `input -j reject` justo arriba del `forward -j reject`, que queden primero los accept y al final los reject

Answer (score 0):

Me siento apenado por una pregunta tan larga por un error tan simple.

Estaba enviando las ordenes por sudo y debía hacerlo directamente desde el usuario root. Envié las ordenes de nuevo como root y problema resuelto.

No se si eliminar la pregunta, lo dejo a discreción de la comunidad.

Feliz día.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy buscando otra respuesta encontré este hilo. Aunque es viejo pero si a alguien le sirve otra persona puede acabar aquí por otro problema común muy parecido. Si no logran poner el puerto a escucha deben poner en consola, en **superusuario** no lo olviden:

```
nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Y dentro sale algo así como:

```
Listen 80
```

Debes agregar abajo o arriba el puerto que necesitas (Listen xxx) guarda con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.